Get periodic updates from a process
I have a function which will increment a number with time. This is given to a process; but it doesn't increment while the process runs. I want the incremented value of my global variable at regular intervals. But, I am not seeing the increment happening.
Here is what I tried:
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

x = 0;

def increment():
  global x;
  while(1):
    x +=1
    sleep(1)


process_1 = Process(target=increment)
process_1.start()

for i in range(0,10):
  print(x);
  sleep(2)

I am expecting that it will print
1
3
5
7 ...

However, it remains at 0.
What am I missing here?

Note that each process is a separate object(). You should pass the vars in the process, to be locally saved in the memory.
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from time import sleep


def increment(x):
    while True:
        x.value += 1
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Value('i', 1)
    process_1 = Process(target=increment, args=(x,))
    process_1.start()

    for i in range(10):
        print(f'{i}: {x.value}')
        sleep(2)


Prints
0: 1
1: 3
2: 5
3: 7
4: 9
5: 11
6: 13
7: 15
8: 17
9: 19


